# Autofixture create class from 3rd party library that has an inaccessible internal constructor

Tags: autofixture

I would like to use Autofixture to create an instance of a class which I am consuming from a 3rd party library.

the problem I am facing is that the constructor of this class has an internal access modifier, and being from a 3rd party solution I cant really use the InternalsVisibleTo attribute, so I was wondering if there is any Autofixture behaviour that can be used or if there are any alternative techniques that can be applied in these kind of scenarios.

```
public class RecordedEvent
  {
    /// <summary>The Event Stream that this event belongs to</summary>
    public readonly string EventStreamId;
    /// <summary>The Unique Identifier representing this event</summary>
    public readonly Guid EventId;
    /// <summary>The number of this event in the stream</summary>
    .....

    internal RecordedEvent(....)
    {
      .....
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OOTB, AutoFixture tries to find a public constructors or static factory method which is able to create an instance of a class. Since you do not own `RecordedEvent` and cannot add public constructor, you have to *teach* AutoFixture how to instantiate it. There is mechanism called [Customizations](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/18/EncapsulatingAutoFixtureCustomizations/) that can be used for that.

First of all you create a *customization* which is able to find all the internal constructors for a type:

```
public class InternalConstructorCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<RecordedEvent>(c =>
            c.FromFactory(
                new MethodInvoker(
                    new InternalConstructorQuery())));
    }

    private class InternalConstructorQuery : IMethodQuery
    {
        public IEnumerable<IMethod> SelectMethods(Type type)
        {
            if (type == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type)); }

            return from ci in type.GetTypeInfo()
                    .GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                   select new ConstructorMethod(ci) as IMethod;
        }
    }
}
```

then you apply it to your `Fixture`:

```
var fixture = new Fixture()
    .Customize(new InternalConstructorCustomization());
```

and after that you can create instances of the `RecordedEvent` class:

```
var recordedEvent = fixture.Create<RecordedEvent>(); // does not throw
```